# How to interpret lm() coefficients when using bs (splines) in R?

Tags: r, splines, lm

I have gone the existing related questions without clarifying my doubt. For the above summary results of a lm() model using bs splines, I would like to fully understand how to interpret the coefficients of the summary below: What do they stand for?, what is their relationship with the knots and with the degree?

```
Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ bs(displacement, degree = 2, df = 6), data = datosA.train)

Residuals:
      Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
 -11.6694  -2.3010  -0.4294   2.1306  20.2003 

Coefficients:
                                       Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
 (Intercept)                            26.5191     2.2309  11.887  < 2e-16 ***
 bs(displacement, degree = 2, df = 6)1  10.5802     2.9502   3.586 0.000390 ***
 bs(displacement, degree = 2, df = 6)2   0.1433     2.2149   0.065 0.948467    
 bs(displacement, degree = 2, df = 6)3  -3.4700     2.6569  -1.306 0.192521    
 bs(displacement, degree = 2, df = 6)4  -9.0744     2.3698  -3.829 0.000156 ***
 bs(displacement, degree = 2, df = 6)5 -13.4888     2.6519  -5.087 6.37e-07 ***
 bs(displacement, degree = 2, df = 6)6 -13.2385     2.7761  -4.769 2.87e-06 ***
 ---
 Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

 Residual standard error: 4.143 on 306 degrees of freedom
 Multiple R-squared:  0.7172, Adjusted R-squared:  0.7116 
 F-statistic: 129.3 on 6 and 306 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the clarification. Very, very useful. I would appreciate a lot if you could help me in clarifying two additional points:
- The possibility of getting the coefficients of the different splines functions using R (lm & bs functions)
- The formula to obtaine the number of degrees of freedom of a bs spline model based on the number of coefficients and the knots. Thanks so, so much in advance

Comment: @ManuelGonzálezFernández Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find 
information on how to do this in the **My Account** 
section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.

Answer (score 5):

Each of your coefficient belongs to a different B-spline basis function (think of them as locally defined polynomials of order $l$, we come to that later) evaluated at the respective covariate values. **The coefficients are not directly interpretable**, i.e. statements like "if $x$ increases $y$ increases/decreases on average by $\beta_p$" are not feasible.
In your case, what the coefficients do is they **scale** the evaluated B-spline basis functions according to the data in order to fit a nice curve.

A very good depiction of this idea can be found in the book [Regression](https://www.springer.com/de/book/9783642343322) by Fahrmeir, L., Kneib, Th., Lang, S., Marx, B.D, page 431.[image]

In panel **a** you see the unscaled basis functions without any relevance of the coefficients. In panel **b** you see the scaled B-spline bases (e.g. positive coefficients lead to parabulas above the zero line and vice versa; the higher the coefficient, the higher the scaled parabula etc.). In panel **c** the scale bases are just summed up to form a smooth line that fits the data nicely. Note that the construction principle of the B-spline bases ensures that the parabulas can be smoothly joint together.

This explanation also reveals the **gist of B-splines** in general: since each locally defined basis gets its own coefficient we are able to perform local smoothing. So in comparison to a simple polynomial approach that assumes the same amount of wiggliness over the whole curve, by using B-splines we can incorporate local differences in wiggliness.

The aforementioned **spline degree** $l$ controls the order of the polynomial included in the B-spline bases. Setting $l=0$ leads to a straight line, while $l=3$ leads to a cubic spline. In other words, $l$ governs the amount of maximum wiggliness your spline can achieve. You find another nice depiction of this idea on page 427 in the same book: [image: Regression] Setting $l$ is actually pretty simple as most approaches just use $l=3$ as the default to get a twice differentiable function.

The question about the **influence of the knots** is a little bit more complicated as there is no default setting (this is where P-splines come into play, I will conclude with a short explanation later). A very general explanation is that the number of knots $m$ (I assume equidistant knots here) controls the "locality" of your spline. Usually, a higher number of knots leads to more flexible functions and vice versa. You can find a comparison on page 425 in the same book: [image: Regression]
As you can see, the fitted curve becomes wigglier the higher the number of knots is set.

The relationship between the different parameters is $d = m + l -1$ where $d$ is the number of basis functions/coefficients, $m$ is the number of knots and $l$ is the degree of the spline.

If you do not want to worry about the number of knots, you should **consider P-Splines** as a convenient alternative. They are based on the the idea of generously setting a high number of knots (usually $20$) to ensure flexibility and then introducing an additional penalty term that prevents overfitting. This is the way to go in a majority of cases where splines are used.