# Interpreting a GAM model output

Tags: generalized-additive-model, gamm4

I have been working on a GAM regressing model with interaction and the summary output have several parameter coefficient and also a some approximate significant of smooth terms. Do u need to interpret the parameter coefficients same way I will do for a linear mode? This is my GAM model:

```
model1 <-gam(list(A ~ Background + 
                      s(center_scale_pconc, by=Background, k=5, bs="tp"),
                  B ~ Background +
                      s(center_scale_pconc, by=Background, k=5, bs="tp"),
                  C ~ Background +
                      s(center_scale_pconc, by=Background, k=5, bs="tp")),
             family  = mvn(d=3), data = data2018, method = "REML")
```

[image]

Comment: I tried to answer this here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/546829/how-to-interpret-lm-coefficients-when-using-bs-splines-in-r/546860#546860 Hope this helps!